# Sass nested style bring ignored/invalid

Tags: sass, vuejs2

I am working on a Vue application which is using `@import url()` and my nested style is shown as the image attached below. I found out that as I am using external .scss that is why it why my styles aren't converted to css but  I don't understand why? and what to do about it.
following is my code

```
  li{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eaeaea;
    background: #fff;
  a{
    div{
      border: 1px solid red;
    }
  }
}
```

[image]
[image: mixin not picked up]

There is no error while compiling as well.

Comment: Is that in an external file? Or inline? Did you use `<style lang="scss">`?

Comment: @brombeer external file. I am using @import to import style and yes I am using `<style lang="scss">`

Comment: Can you paste the whole style section code of your file ? Also, you did not forget the semicolon at the end `@import url();`, this one is important.

Comment: Hi, any news from you after some given updates here ?

Answer (score 3):

That looks like you included SASS code to your html.
If you may like you should check:

1. In your `html` file: did you really linkt the `.css` file to your html or did you link the `.scss` file to html.
2. In your `CSS`file: is the SASS code compiled at all.

---

**UPDATE: ERROR RECONSTRUCTED**

What I did:

Added This code to a CSS file `style.css` ...

```
li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
  background: red;
  a {
    div {
      border: 1px solid red;
    }
  }
}
```

Linked that to my HTML: `<link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">`

... and got follwing error in Chrome:

[image: Reconstructed Error in Chrome]

**RESULT: It is raw SCSS code which is includeded in a source which is marked as CSS so the browser is interpreting it as CSS**

Note: Including as `.scss` file instead was not the same result.

I am not quite sure about the difference to your error which names `<style>` as source (in picture top right edge). But if you click on the source link in the browser it should lead you to the source.

Up from here is no chance to follow the error.
So please check your CSS sources:

1. Is the `.css` file the right one: maybe your are writing your SCSS in a CSS file which off course does not compile. That could happen i.e. when you setup the project and do a misspelling creating the SCSS file.
2. Maybe that code is added to the `<style>` tag in the head or body (added by a module or whatever) or is it marked as `<style lang="css">`

... or any other method to add/link css

**Indeed best way is to check all your linked css sources.**
That cannot be done up from here without more information :-(

Also possible but VERY ATYPICAL FOR THAT ERROR PATTERN: maybe check your SASS compiler once more ... if it is an unknown issue which blocks it to compile.

Comment: I m using node-sass, css-loader etc that come with vuejs to complplie it

Comment: Try to provide us as much debugging info as possible if you want us to check if it's working. Thinking that you did something well is usually not enough to be sure that the setup is done in the good way. Also, giving the project structure can be good. Or, more simple: a [repro]

Comment: Updated the answer: reconstructed/identified the reason for that issue.

Comment: Totally logic behavior for me: `SCSS` do have the ability to do nesting while regular `CSS` cannot (yet). So, if you do not use webpack or alike to bundle it, it will stay as SCSS but the browser is not able to read SCSS directly. The final style that is shipped needs to be regular CSS. Congratz for your efforts into making the 90% of the debugging effort **for** the OP. Now, he can maybe give us his configuration about the whole thing. cc @localhost

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code snippet, you simply forgot to close a bracket ? Try to provide a properly indented snippet of code like this

```css
li {
  background: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
  border-bottom: 1px solid hsl(0, 0%, 92%);
  a {
    div {
      border: 1px solid hsl(60, 85%, 57%);
    }
  }
}
```

And if you meant

```css
li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  background: #fff;
}

a {
  div {
    border: 1px solid red;
  }
}
```

Here is your solution so far.

Also, as stated in my comment, you do need to not forget the `;` at the end of your import, like `@import '~cool_stuff';`. ESlint can really help on this and is backed into the CLI generated project.

Comment: I wish it was that simple but not. I updated my question to add new screenshot

Comment: The result is not useful here since there is an error in the code causing that result. Prefer posting the whole code.